# AspectJ, SpringAOP, Aspect runs twice

Tags: java, spring, aspectj, spring-aop

My aspect runs twice and I don't see a reason why. Maybe someone could point me on my mistake?
Here is a code:

1. Creating annotation for pointcut

   ```
   @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
   @Target({ElementType.METHOD})
   public @interface CustodianMetrics {
       String metricId();
   }
   ```
2. Creating an aspect

   ```
   @Aspect
   @Component("custodianMetricsAspect")
   public class CustodianMetricsAspect {
       private final MonitoringService monitoringService;

       @Autowired
       public CustodianMetricsAspect(MonitoringService monitoringService) {
           this.monitoringService = monitoringService;
       }

       @After("@annotation(custodianMetricsAnnotation)")
       public void count(CustodianMetrics custodianMetricsAnnotation) {
           Counter metric = monitoringService.metric(custodianMetricsAnnotation.metricId(), Counter.class);
           metric.inc();
       }
   }
   ```
3. Configuring xml for spring

   ```
   <aop:aspectj-autoproxy>
       <aop:include name="path"/>
   </aop:aspectj-autoproxy>
   <aop:config>
       <aop:aspect id="custodianMetricsAspect" ref="custodianMetricsAspect">
           <aop:after method="count" 
                    pointcut="@annotation(custodianMetricsAnnotation)"/>
       </aop:aspect>
   </aop:config>
   ```

I tried to change poitcut on this

```
@After("@annotation(custodianMetricsAnnotation) && execution(* *(..))")
```

But the same result - aspect runs twice. Any suggestions?

Comment: As a possibly unrelated suggestion, you should limit the pointcuts to a package level, i.e. `execution(public * org.mypackage..*.*(..))`.

Comment: If component scan for your `@Component` aspect is active, @Nikolas could be right with his answer. But just to make sure it is really the same joinpoint triggered twice and not another class being intercepted unexpectedly because it also bears the same annotation, you could add `JoinPoint thisJoinPoint` as the first parameter to your `count()` advice and just print it to the console like `System.out.println(thisJoinPoint)`. Then you really know for sure.

Answer (score 3):

It happens because you have configured the aspect ***twice*** - both Spring XML configuration and the `@Aspect` annotation.

Read the note in section [8.1.2 Spring AOP capabilities and goals](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-introduction-spring-defn)  of Spring framework documentation, it states the following:

> One such choice that is relevant to this chapter is that of which AOP framework (and which AOP style) to choose. You have the choice of AspectJ and/or Spring AOP, and you also have the choice of either the @AspectJ annotation-style approach or the Spring XML configuration-style approach.

In this case, based on my personal experience, I highly recommend you to stick with the annotations. However, it depends on your personal taste. You may find [8.4 Choosing which AOP declaration style to use](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-choosing) relevant.

Edit:
If you choose the annotation-based configuration, don't forget to create a Java configuration class instead of deleted `<aop:aspectj-autoproxy>...` line.

```
@Configuration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
public class AspectJAutoProxyConfiguration { }
```

Comment: `<aop:aspectj-autoproxy> <aop:include name="path"/> </aop:aspectj-autoproxy>` Wen i use this config aspect didnt run at all

Comment: You need a Java configuration (empty) class annotated with `@Configuration
` and `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy`.